# extracting a number from a string based on length

Tags: string, extract

m179.90 L‘ASYRO SIZE L SMLXLXXL 40.70089.01.0600.L “Willi!!!” Ml! 7//297563 787049 Gray

a.I am building an ocr bot ,it currently outputs the above..

b.I need a general code that will find 40.70089.01.0600.L = = = 18 caricatures  based on its length and return only the 4070098 without dot's so first 8 digits - dot.

Comment: "caricatures": you mean characters, presumably ?

Comment: Splitting a string is trivial. So what is your problem ?

Comment: Can you include more sample data, and also tell us which language/tool you are using to handle this problem?

Comment: What is the language and the logic? Is this always in this pattern `40.70089.01.0600.L`?  `4070098 without dot's so first 8 digits`, do you mean 7 digits?